# Multi-Threading application crashed due to unvalid lock management

Tags: c++

I have a multi-threading process which executing the `callback` below with different value of msg_name and lines. The goal is to log the lines to msg_name file. To avoid unvalid writing to the log file i added locks on each msg_name `m_lockers[msg_name]` with m_globalLock to avoid creating different locks on the same msg_name. When the process is speed up. The application crashed at `m_lockers[msg_name]->acquire();`. Did any one have a solution for this problem.

```
void callback(const std::string& msg_name, const std::vector<std::string>& lines)
{
    m_lockers[msg_name];
    if(m_lockers[msg_name] == nullptr)
    {
        m_globalLock.acquire();
        if(m_lockers[msg_name] == nullptr)
        {
            m_lockers[msg_name] = new ExclusiveLock();
        }
        m_globalLock.release();
    }
    m_lockers[msg_name]->acquire();
    for(auto it=lines.begin(); it!=lines.end();it++)
    {
        process(msg_name, *it);
    }
    m_lockers[msg_name]->release();
}

ExclusiveLock                            m_globalLock;
std::map<std::string,ExclusiveLock*>     m_lockers;
```

Comment: The first two lines of `callback` access `m_lockers[msg_name]` *without* having acquired `m_globalLock`.  So you potentially have multiple threads reading/writing `m_lockers` without any synchronization.  That's undefined behaviour.

Comment: the line `m_lockers[msg_name];` doesn't initialize the value of the map, so it potentially contains a garbage value and will pass the null check

Comment: @xEric_xD that's wrong, `operator[]` will create a value-initialized value in the map if the key doesn't exist. And for a pointer value that will become a zero-initialized pointer (which is a null pointer)